# Deploy a sailsjs application and background processing(python) on aws ec2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, sails.js

I am using sailsjs as my app's backend and python alongwith kafka for background processing. Now I want to deploy everything on aws ec2 with ubuntu.I am having multiple questions in my mind regarding how to achieve the above task:

Q1: Should I deploy everything on one ec2 instance? If yes, then I'll have to use 5 daemon processes for sails, zookeeper, kafka and 2 python scripts. Now is it possible/advisable to create these many daemon processes?

Q2: What is a better option for background processing: The one that I am using or should I use node-resque for achieving the same?

Thanks in advance for your advice.